# WrapPanel children order

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

i use WPF and add WrapPanel children in User Control panel.
like that:

```
SearchPanel sp = new SearchPanel();
sp.Clock = clock; 
sp.Name = item.CustomerTwo;
sp.Color = "Purple";
wPanel.Children.Add(sp);
```

how i organize this added panels

Comment: How do you want to organize them? What happens instead?

Comment: i added 3 type panels in the wrap. random colors purple, gray, red. i want sort them with colors

Comment: What happens if you sort them first and then add them to the `WrapPanel`?

Comment: im not sure how do that. there is all part the code:   https://www.codepile.net/pile/aVMaPPV9

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this question is that they appear in the order that they are added to the Children collection.

If you were adding them explicitly using XAML they would appear in the same order that they appear in the XAML.

If you were adding them by binding the ItemsSource of the WrapPanel then they would appear in the order that the bound collection presents them.

---

As for your specific example...

In your linked code, the colour is based on a date indirectly obtained from each "customer" item. To order the WrapPanel based on this, you will need to sort your customer items by that same criteria first.

Unfortunately, the date logic is convoluted (using a DB relation to a Days table and then some awkward date manipulation code). You could use that convoluted date logic in a Comparison function to sort the customer items first. Or you could add a property to the "newSearchPanel" class which you calculate while constructing them and add them to a temp list, which you sort before finally pushing them into the WrapPanel.